# Encrypt String in Lua, Decrypt in PHP?

Tags: php, lua

I'm attempting to find a method (with no results) on how to create a function in PHP and Lua where you can hash/encrypt a string in Lua, (It then sends in a Post request to my domain) and then decrypt that now hashed/encrypted string in php, all help would be appreciated.

ex.
Lua:

```
    local string = "Hello World"
    local encrypted = encrypt(string)
    api:HttpPost("my.website.com/php", encrypted)
```

ex. PHP:

```
   <?php
   $input = file_get_contents("php://input");
   $unhashed = $unhash(input);
   echo($unhashed);
   ?>
```

Then it would echo "Hello World", Anyone know how to do this.

Comment: encryption != hashing

Comment: what type of encryption does lua's `encrypt()` do?

Comment: None, it's an example I just need some sort of hashing method so I can do it.